# How can I serve a static file to my local Kubernetes deployed service from my controller file?

Tags: go, kubernetes, jwt

I have defined a deployment file:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ ... }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ ... }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ ... }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
    ...
```

My service implements JWT validation and thus requires a public key. Can I somehow specify in the deployment file to serve a locally generated pub key file to my service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) suggested by @Crou to create the key:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic pub-key --from-file=./jwt-key.pub
```

and then mounted it to a volume in my deployment yaml:

```
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: secret
      secret:
        secretName: pub-key
        defaultMode: 256
...
  containers:
      volumeMounts:
        - name: secret
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /secret
```

and was able to access my key at `/secret/jwt-key.pub`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `configmaps`. Config maps are resources that are used to deploy single files (basically). I'm currently using one for my clusters nginx configuration.

In your config file , write the contents of your public key to your data field and then tell your deployment to use that config file and read from it. It's very similar to mounting a volume for a single file only. You may need to update your deployed image to read from the mounted location though.

Search for `nginx in kubernetes` for examples of how people use configmaps to deploy their configurations (in your case public key) to the clusters.

For testing you can create your config map with this command `kubectl create configmap public-conf --from-file=./your-public-key`. This will create a configmap called public-conf. You can run `kubectl get configmap` to see your newly created configmap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way to configure it so that it copies from a local file so that anyone spinning up can just generate the pub key and be good to go rather than having to dump the file contents into the yaml file?

Comment: I’m not sure I understood correctly. Do you want kubernetes to access to your local file system automatically ? That’s not possible. You have to deploy your contents to the cloud one way or another, or use an endpoint that writes uploaded keys to a database.

Comment: You can use a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) to hold the key. Or if you want to generate it each time you create a new pod, you can look into [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

Comment: @atayenel I don't want to manually copy/paste a key into a configmap file every time someone locally wants to spin up.